# update a variable in a method call

Tags: javascript

in a loop i am calling the method bullet.fire(); in this method i have this.i++, the only trouble is this.i does not update on every iteration, any idea why?

```
function projectile(){
    this.i = 20;
}

projectile.prototype.fire = function(){
    this.i++;
    //shows value of this.i in a div
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = this.i;
}
```

in the loop

```
if(typeof(bullet) == "undefined"){
    var bullet = new projectile(1);
}

bullet.fire();
```

Comment: I copied and run your code (without `document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = this.i` and it worked as expected.

Comment: It updates fine, it just updates all at once so you don't see it updating. Put an `alert(bullet.i);` in the loop and you will see it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does fire!

You don’t see the progress for two reasons. First, there is no delay, so it happens instantaneously. Secondly, the javascript works in one synchronous thread. The interface (HTML) is not refreshed until the thread is finished.

You can break the thread by using one of JavaScripts asynchronous execution methods. `setInterval` for an instance:

```
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function projectile(){
    this.i = 20;
}

projectile.prototype.fire = function(){
    this.i++;
    //shows value of this.i in a div
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = this.i;
}

var i = 3, bullet = new projectile(1), timer;

timer = setInterval(function () { 
    bullet.fire();
    if (--i <= 0) clearInterval(timer);
}, 300);
</script>
```

[In action on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8x3vw/1/)